# Failed to instantiate module myApp due to: Error: [$injector:nomod]

Tags: angularjs

I am having an error on this code. I don't know why I am using angularjs 1.7.x version

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#signupBtn-spinner').hide();

    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    $('#signupBtn').click(signup);
    function signup() {
        app.controller('signupController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            alert('hello')
        }]);
    }    
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I strongly recommend you to avoid to use jquery with Angular/js

If you want to implement signup/login logic, suggest you to use [ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/ng1/). Some [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vDURUN?p=preview&preview).

Also please read this great Josh David Miller's answer [“Thinking in AngularJS” if I have a jQuery background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

---

About your problem:

You get this error from `ng-app`.

Put `var app = angular.module('myApp', []);` out of `$(document).ready`

Angularjs is loaded and it does not see any module because it is still not ready.

---

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#signupBtn-spinner').hide();
    
    $('#signupBtn').click(signup);
    function signup() {
        app.controller('signupController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            alert('hello')
        }]);
    }    
})
```